# Chain Rule and Multivariable calculus

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I would be very grateful if anyone could assist with the following:

Given that $$ z = yg(x^2-y^2) $$ I'm trying to show that:

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial z }{\partial x} + \frac{1}{y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{z}{y^2}$$

I've started by doing the following (is this correct?):
 $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = yg(x^2 - y^2) \times 2x \times\frac{dg}{dx}$$

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = g(x^2-y^2)-2y^2g(x^2 -y^2)\frac{dg}{dy}$$

My question: is it necessary to add $\frac{dg}{dx}$ and $\frac{dg}{dy}$ to the above?

I tend to struggle a bit with these sort of questions involving differentiating undefined functions like g. Would anyone kindly point to where I find more questions of this sort-perhaps even on MSE?

Thanks for your assistance.

Edit: I've now realised my mistake was in assuming that g was a function of x and y when its just a function of one variable. Thanks for your explanation and answers.

Comment: Are you sure that $g$ is not constant?

Comment: @OccupyGezi, I believe g is an undefined function of x and y. Isn't it?

Comment: No, it is a constant; see the answer below

Comment: @Occupy Gezi, Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Be carefull; g is not a function. If it would be the result will not hold.

Comment: Isn't g a function of one variable though rather than two variables?

Comment: No, it is not. When you assume it is a function you can't prove the equality. It is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g$ is function of one variable $t=x^2-y^2$ and you have:
$z_x=2xyg'$, where subscript under $z$ denotes partial differentiation w.r.t. x. Do you now understand what was the mistake?

Comment: Yes, thanks. How can you tell that g is function of one variable from $g(x^2-y^2)$? I think that was the source of my error.

Comment: That is hidden in notation. In parentheses there is only "one slot" and $x^2-y^2$ is substituted. I will give you one more example: consider $f(x,y)=g(x^2+y,x-y)$. Then g is function of two variables, call them $u,v$ for example and with $u=x^2+y$,  $v=x-y$, "feeded" into them. Then $f_x=2xg_u+g_v$. Can you figure out what is $f_y$?

Comment: that was an excellent explanation. I believe $f_{y} = g_{u} - g_{v}$

Comment: That's correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$z = ygx^2-gy^3$$
$$dz = gx^2dy+2ygxdx-3gy^2dy$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = gx^2-3gy^2$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2ygx$$

Now replacing these into the equation
$$\frac{1}{x}2ygx + \frac{1}{y}(gx^2-3gy^2) = 2yg + \frac{gx^2}{y}-3gy $$
$$=-gy + \frac{gx^2}{y}=  \frac{gyx^2-gy^3}{y^2}=\frac{gy(x^2-y^2)}{y^2}=\frac{z}{y^2}$$